# 秘密鍵生成時のユーザー名は完全一致する必要がある？

Tags: ios, monaca

iOSのデバッグビルドがうまくいかない状態です。

エラーメッセージ（一部）
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.2'

同様の現象の方だと秘密鍵とPorivisioningが一致しているか再確認したら、成功した、と報告がありましたが、まだ解決しておりません。

MonacaIDEで秘密鍵を生成する時の説明文に
「ユーザー名とメールアドレスは iOS Dev Center の登録情報と完全に一致している必要があります」と記載がありますが、AppleDeveloperの登録を日本語で登録してしまい、MonacaIDEで秘密鍵生成時に日本語を入力すると「Fail to create CSR」とエラーになってしまいます。

MonacaIDEに記載されている、「ユーザー名とメールアドレスは iOS Dev Center の登録情報と完全に一致している必要があります」は本当に必要なのでしょうか？
一致しなくてもビルド出来るよー、という方がいらっしゃれば、１つ原因が潰れるのですが。

Appleサポートには名前を日本語→英語に変更して下さい、と連絡しているのですが、３日待っても連絡がない状態でして…。

Answer (score 1):

アカウントの登録名を、英語で登録しなおして、登録したアドレス（ＩＤ）と英語名で生成し直してもだめですか？

もし駄目なら新たにアカウント作るのが一番早いかな、と思います。

Comment: AppleDeveloper登録名を変えたくない事情があったものでして…。

たった今の話ですが、以下の資料を見ながらやったところ、ビルド出来ました。
http://www.slideshare.net/mobilebackend/2-monacambaas

iOSのビルドはなかなか難しいです…

Comment: appleは審査までにも時間かかって怖いですね。ぼくもちょっとずつお勉強します。